# JNI jstring from class variable?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have in my Java class a string variable:

```
public class myclass {
    protected final String file;
    myclass(String f) {
        file = f;
    }

    public native void processFiles();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myclass mc = new myclass(args[0]);
        mc.processFiles();
    }
}
```

In C++, I have:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_myclass_processFiles(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jclass baseClass = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(baseClass, "file", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jchar filename = env->GetCharField(baseClass, fid);
    jstring fileFieldString = env->NewString(&filename, sizeof(filename));
    const char *nativeFileString = env->GetStringUTFChars(fileFieldString, NULL);
    printf("JNI: File path: %s\n", nativeFileString);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(fileFieldString, nativeFileString);
}
```

My output is:

```
JNI: File path: ??2
```

What am I doing wrong that isn't converting the Java string to the char* string properly? I am providing the path ~/Desktop/myfile as the sole argument, so there is a value in args[0]. My thought was that sizeof(filename) wasn't right, but there's no other option from what I can tell.

I did try this: [JNI. How to get jstring from jobject and convert it to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501253/jni-how-to-get-jstring-from-jobject-and-convert-it-to-char) but when I typecast the result from GetObjectField() to jstring, I get an error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001043111e8, pid=6191, tid=3591
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3111e8]  jni_GetStringUTFChars+0x66
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

Also, this is just JNI and Java 8 on OSX, nothing related to Android.

Thank you.

Update:
I was able to get a friend to look at it, and got it working with:

```
jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(baseClass, "file", "Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring jstr = (jstring) env->GetObjectField(thiz, fid);
const char *nativeFileString = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, NULL);
printf("JNI: File path: %s\n", nativeFileString);
```

Comment: Just pass it as a paramater to the JNI method. Try not to write one more line of JNI than strictly necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing `jchar filename = env->GetCharField(baseClass, fid);`

But `fid` is a field of type `Ljava/lang/String;`, not a `char`. So you should get that `String` using `env->GetObjectField()` and then follow what that link says.

You can also debug this better by adding `env->ExceptionDescribe()` after every line to see if an `Exception` is being thrown after your calls to `env` (that would be just to debug, in real production code you should be checking for exceptions after every `env` call and do something if something goes wrong).

By the way, maybe your code is just an example, but if that's your real code, it would be a lot easier to declare the `native` method as `static` and just pass the string as a parameter.

Comment: I was able to get it working, GetObjectField() was the appropriate function.